# Как в Visual Studio сохранять наборы открытых файлов в проекте и переключаться между этими наборами?

Tags: visual-studio

Суть такая - есть большой проект, и хочется переключаться между пресетами из открытых файлов (классов), в зависимости от текущей задачи.
Например, нужно поработать с классом А - открываем пресет (набор открытых файлов) с  контроллером, представлением, частичными представлениями, скриптами специфичными для класса А.  Потом раз - закрываем лишнее, и переходим к пресету для работы с классом Б. И переключаемся между ними не открывая каждый файл вручную. Механизм как в Опере с сохранением сессий.  Есть в студии такие функции? Студия 2019 превью 3.

Comment: В меню: Window > Save Window Layout.

Comment: К сожалению, это не то. Ваш совет сохраняет расположение окон интерфейса (Solution explorer window, bookmark window, property window), а не вкладок с открытыми файлами.

Comment: А, понял. Можно попробовать расширение для Студии [Save All the Tabs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.SaveAlltheTabs)

Comment: Да, это то что нужно! Спасибо за помощь! Буду ждать когда добавят поддержку VS2019.

Answer (score 1):

Полгода прошло, и вот оно : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreyVeselov.WorkspaceManager
может кому пригодится